# SQL Multiple condition on single field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi Can someone help me about sql

i have this data in my Table:

```
date_added | location     |  status
2012-08-01    Manila           1
2012-08-01    Japan            1
2012-08-01    Cebu             1

2012-08-04    Manila           1
2012-08-04    Cebu             1
2012-08-04    Africa           1

2012-08-06    Manila           1
2012-08-06    Japan            1
2012-08-06    Cebu             1
```

how can i get the date_added result with the location in 'Manila' , 'Japan', 'Cebu' and has status =1

The three data must exist before i can get the date.

Result should be: based on this table

```
date_added 
 2012-08-01
 2012-08-06
```

since on 2012-08-04  'Japan' did not exists.

My Current SAMPLE SQL:

```
SELECT date_added FROM TABLE WHERE location ='Manila' AND location ='Japan' 
       AND location ='Cebu' AND STATUS =1;
```

Please help.....any help will greatly appreciated

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
SELECT DATE_ADDED 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE LOCATION IN ('MANILA' , 'JAPAN' , 'CEBU')
AND STATUS =1
GROUP BY DATE_ADDED
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT LOCATION)=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the SQL `IN` operator:

```
SELECT date_added FROM TABLE WHERE location IN ('Manila', 'Japan', 'Cebu') AND STATUS =1;
```

Or alternatively, you need to use the `OR` operator and bracket the location statements:

```
SELECT date_added FROM TABLE WHERE ( location ='Manila' OR location ='Japan' OR location ='Cebu' ) AND STATUS =1;
```

Comment: Either of these statements will give 2012-08-04 in the output.  I don't think this is what the OP wants - he wants only the dates on which Manila, Cebu AND Japan appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT date_added FROM TABLE WHERE location ='Manila' or location ='Japan'  or location ='Cebu' AND STATUS =1;
```

or

```
select date_added FROM TABLE WHERE location in ('Manila','Japan','Cebu') AND status='1' GROUPED BY date_added
```

Comment: this query will give 2012-08-04 also

Comment: the first query should use some parentheses around the location conditions

Comment: BAD practice mixing of 'AND' and 'OR'. You should also bracket the OR's. Does this mean (Manila OR Japan OR cebu) AND status=1 --or-- Manila OR Japan OR (cebu and status=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE location IN ('Manila' , 'Japan', 'Cebu') AND status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `AND` condition on the same field,it will always result to false because a field can only have `1 possible value`. So you needto use `IN` for that

```
SELECT Date_added 
FROM   myTable
WHERE  `Location` IN ('MANILA' , 'JAPAN' , 'CEBU')
          AND `Status` =1
GROUP BY Date_added 
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT Location) = 3
```